# Check data being returned in a .then AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, debugging, angular-promise, es6-promise

I am trying to figure out the best way to check what is being returned to my response in my `.then{}`

for example can I add a console.log to the .then{} to see what is being returned if anything?

Below is my unsuccessful attempt at checking this data:

```
return myValidationService.getUserDetails(userId)
                        .then(response => response.data.data
                          //This is where I want to add my log
                          console.log("This is my response data: " + response.data.data))
                        .catch(error => pageErrorService.go(pageErrorService.errorDetails.genericError, error));
```

I am getting complaints from my linter about the above syntax though.

What is the standard way of checking this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In angular1.x it goes in this way:

```
.then(function(response){
  console.log(response.data);
})
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought I had added it to the function like that but for some reason my linter was complaining about the ";" not sure what I missed when I tried it but that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here in the syntax

```
return myValidationService.getUserDetails(userId)
     .then(response => response.data.data
       //This is where I want to add my log
       console.log("This is my response data: " + response.data.data))
     .catch(error => ....));
```

You are using fat arrow in the code:

```
 .then(response => response.data.data
      //This is where I want to add my log
       console.log(...)
  )
```

The above code is same as writing

```
.then(function(response){
   return response.data.data
})
```

The above code is returning the value, before it being consoled

Adding curly brackets will work in your case. You can write something like this to log the value:

```
 .then(response => {
      console.log(...);
      return response.data.data;
  })
```

Comment: Nothing to do with angular. It's an ES6 syntax